# java.net.ConnectException only on Windows

Tags: java, networking, connectionexception

I am trying to do a little java application which downloads some pictures and then computes them to one. (So a puzzle solver) It works perfectly fine on Linux, but however I am getting this stacktrace (plus a few lines). And I have no Idea why this is working on Linux (Ubuntu KDE 17.10), but not on Windows (10). Googling around has not helped because I am always landing on Minecraft related questions which have not helped me so far.

I am using jdk1.8.0_131.

Thanks for your efforts!

Here is the download Method:

```
public byte[] download(URL url) {
        byte[] response = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int n = 0;
            while (-1 != (n = in.read(buf))) {
                out.write(buf, 0, n);
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
            response = out.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> Alerts.ExceptionDialog(e,"IOException","Fehler bei der Verbindung"));
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
```

Comment: Firewall problem.

Comment: @EJP Which side? Client or Server? And I looked my PC firewall rules up and there is Java added!

Comment: @EJP I completly disable my firewall and still there is the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site where I wanted to get my files from was offline while I tested my program && My program sent to much request to the server.